# appending pointers to class to a QList QList<Class* >

Tags: c++, pointers, append, constants, qlist

In my mainwindow.h I have a QList m_qlServoList which should store pointers to Servo objects:

```
QList<Servo* > m_qlServoList;
```

When I try to append a new Servo pointer to the QList:

```
m_qlServoList.append(new Servo(iID, iBaudRate));
```

The following Error results:

```
passing 'const QList<Servo*>' as 'this' argument of 'void QList<T>::append(const T&) [with T = Servo*]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

The Servo class header looks as follows:

```
class Servo
{
public:
    Servo(const int &iID, const int &iBaudRate);
    ~Servo();

    void write_data(Data const& data) const;
    Data& receive_data() const;

private:
    Data m_oData;
};
```

It would be great if someone can explain me what I am doing wrong here. And how to correctly append pointers to Servo objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we lack informations, it's likely that your `QList<Servo *>` is `const`.

This could happen if your call was made from a `const` method of the class holding the `QList`.

Lets see an example:

```
class MyClass
    {
        private:
          QList<Servo *> m_qlServoList;
        public:
          void addServo(Servo *ptr) const /* Notice the const here */
            {
              m_qlServoList.append(prt); 
            }
     };

/* from main */
MyClass c;
c.addServo(new Servo(iID, iBaudRate));
```

This code wouldn't compile, because the `addServo()` method is `const`, which means that `m_qlServoList` will be considered as a `const QList<Servo *>`.

Comment: Thanks @Xaqq for your help and the example, it solved the problem! 
Sorry for not providing more information about the method calling the `m_qlServoList.append()` function. The `const` keyword was the reason for the error.